Prove that an infinite well ordered set X has equal cardinality to the set X∪{a}, where 'a' does not belong to X.
Found this question in a book of analysis as a corollary. Before the question is introduced (as an exercise), the book introduced Theorem of Recursion on Wosets and Comparability Theorem. For convenience I post the description of these two theorems using picture format.
Theorem of Recursion on Wosets
Comparability Theorem
The corollary is here:
Corollaries
It seems the corollary should be easy to prove so that the book didn't give an answer to it, lefting it for the readers. I can prove any infinite woset X's cardinality is bigger than N's. The key is to define a function F:N→X by such a way: map 1 to the smallest number in X; and for any number n in N, consider F(pre(n)), if F(pre(n)) does not equal to X, then F(n) will equal to the smallest number in X/F(pre(n)). After such a definiton of F we can consider a subset N0 of N:{n:n∈N and F(pre(n)≠X}, we can verify that N0 and F(N0) are both lower sets (respectively of N and X), and F acts as an order isomorphism between them. By induction we can show that N0 is actually equal to N: conseder the situation that if n in N0 but n+1 not; that means F(pre(n+1)), which is equal to F({1,2,...,n}), will equal to X, by our definition of F. This will mean that X is finite. So every natural number should be in N0 by induction. Then there's an order isomorphism between N and a subset of X, thus Card(X)≥Card(N).
I show this proof because when proving Comparability Theorem the book used a similar way, and I wonder if this may help to solve the next corollary. However, I can't prove Card(X)=Card(X∪{a}), since I really don't know how to connect both sets to N and using the term that X is infinity. After a hard try I gave up, maybe this problem is actually easy but I just didn't found it. Can anyone help me?

Please use MathJax to format your equations.

Hi, welcome to MSE. I think the intended proof of corollary B is to apply the comparability theorem directly to $(X, \preceq)$ and $(\Bbb N, \le)$. (Your proof is probably correct, but you seem to just be typing out the usual proof of the comparability theorem, rather than using it to deduce the corollary. That's what the point of corollaries is!). Then in general it's true for any set that if $|X| \ge |\Bbb N|$, then $|X| + 1 = |X|$. (This follows from $|\Bbb N| + 1 = |\Bbb N|$). Can you fill in the details?

Sorry for Gary, I didn't use MathJax, but actually I didn't show any equations here, I just mean that any infinite woset's cardinality is bigger than N's (I post the proof because I think it may help), but I don't know how to prove that |X|+1=|X|. I still don't know how to use |N|+1=|N| to prove that?
